# mouse button down handling in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I'd like to check when the left button is pressed. In my code i check for click=pygame.mouse.get_pressed()  and then check if the left button is pressed by checking click[0]==1.
This means that what i pass in as an action for the mouse click happens so long click[0]==1. I'd like it to happen just ONCE. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
def button(text, x, y, width, height, inactive_color, active_color, action = None):
    cur = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()          
    print(click)
    if x + width > cur[0] > x and y + height > cur[1] > y:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, active_color, (x,y,width,height))

    if click[0] == 1 and action != None:         # Button action definitions

        if action == "quit":
            print('quit')
            return 0
        if action == "intro":
            print('intro')
            return 1   
        if action == "play":
            print('play')
            return 2
        if action == "replay":    
            print('replay')
            #restart timer?
            return 2
        if action == "controls":           
            print('controls')
            return 3 
        if action == "pause":
            gamePause()
        if action == "continue":                
            paused=False        

else:
    pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, inactive_color, (x,y,width,height))

text_to_button(text,BLACK,x,y,width,height)
```

Comment: use `if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` (and `event.button == 1`). This event is created only once when button changes position from `not-pressed` to `pressed`  but it is not created when you keep pressed. But this would need to rebuild this ugly `button` function into nice class `Button` ie. https://github.com/furas/my-python-codes/blob/master/pygame/button-hover/example-1.py

Answer (score 2):

Keep a mouse button state variable and only count the click if it was previously not down.

```
mouse_state = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
while True:  # game loop  
    pressed = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    clicked = [p - s for p, s in zip(pressed, mouse_state)]
    mouse_state = pressed
    # now clicked[0] is: 1 if mouse clicked, 0 if no change, -1 is released
    ...
```